# Gap of absolutely nothing on my website [HTML/CSS]

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I asked this question last time, and for some odd reason it was closed due to it being "irrelevant." I don't see how this is "irrelevant" at all. I explained the problem thoroughly with high detail. So this is my second attempt.

**The Problem:** There is a big gap on the bottom portion of my website. There is absolutely nothing there, and I have no idea what is causing this problem.

**Image:** [WITHOUT EXPLANATIONS](https://i.gyazo.com/0692debc5a4055856e467dae5684f756.png)

[WITH EXPLANATIONS](https://i.gyazo.com/9da5a8a0278ed5fc7a7c69983eb1aeb0.png)

You get what I'm trying to say? The big gap is what I want to remove. I want my content to end where it ends, but there's a big gap of absolutely nothing after it!

**Website Fiddle:** `Click` [THIS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uhwzjbf5/2/)

So if you scroll down, you can see the big gap of absolute nothingness, yes? That's what I want to fix. Please help me!

Comment: Remove the `top: -382px;` in your `footer` ID. Your [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/uhwzjbf5/3/)

Comment: Your code is horrific. You have several unclosed tags, deprecated tags, and all sorts of css issues. I suggest starting over.

Comment: No. I can't start over, because I will just end up with the same outcome again. I am a beginner and I'm still learning by experience. I am taking courses and tutorials whilst gaining experience with projects like this.

Also, mind telling me where the unclosed tags are? Are they in the HTML or CSS? I just went through the HTML code and found one unclosed tag. I also went to the CSS and found 2 unclosed command tags (without semicolons) and fixed that as well. But where are the other ones?

Comment: @AndreasSkorv, there's so many websites that are teaching `HTML` and `CSS`. I would suggest this [site](https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/htmlcss). That's just one of many out there. Keep exploring.

Comment: I am already taking multiple courses on CodeCademy and saving all of my code in a notepad in Google documents. Thanks though.

Comment: I just found this [link](http://www.beginnersguidetohtml.com/guides/css/layout/div-tags) that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

The `top: -382px;` is causing the space below your footer. Also why not use `margin: 0 auto;` to center the element. And lastly, there's so many `tags` that is **UNCLOSED**.

Change this:

```
#footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  top: -382px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  z-index: -1; }
```

To this:

```
#footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  z-index: -1; }
```

Here's your **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uhwzjbf5/5/)**

Comment: Ok, thanks. I changed my footer to your provided code however there is still a pretty significant gap as you can see in this image.

https://i.gyazo.com/aa57275840837d7e32627b19265c2160.png

You just separated it from the other content. The gap is practically still there.

Comment: Because you are pushing your element to the top using `top`. You don't have to do that unless it is necessary. And also your HTML structure is not organize. **TIP:** Use `div` in every sections/part of your articles etc...

Comment: Ok, so if I use the div with my articles it should fix the gap, correct? I will also be sure to remove the "top" commands from the CSS of my paragraphs. Everything should be in place right?

Comment: Actually, `gap` is not the problem. The way your code flows produce the `gap`.

Comment: Could you tell me how to fix that? Where, in part of my code, do I need to change to fix this gap?

Comment: UPDATE! I've added the divs to my paragraphs. Not much of a significant change, it just made my paragraphs thicker. But I guess it keeps everything organized.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n1k71L9c/

But what do I need to do to fix this gap? I am beginning to become worried about that gap, please help me.

Comment: You're still using the `top` on your css.

Comment: But when I remove the top it puts everything out of place completely. I can't do that or else my objects it will be scattered all over the place.